# How to stream screen content to Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

I have an Android app that I would like to add the ability for the user to "cast" what is displayed on the app to a Chromecast.  It could just be a local JPG but I would prefer the user to actually see actual "live" content of the app.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I know there are apps like AllCast but wasn't sure if they were using supported features of the SDK or if it was a hack.  I found some mention of the Default Media Receiver but could not find any documentation on how to use it with local content.  Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Cast api to do that directly; you can look into WebRTC or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to use the Presentation class. The only problem is that you do need to use the ChromeCast app to start screen mirroring before you start your app.

I have not yet found a way to start mirroring my app (or, to be more precise, to  show the contents of your Presentation class) from a ChromeCast UIButton within my app, even though I have been able to get that cast button working and connecting ... just not to start app-mirroring when using only my in-app chromecast button.